# MongoDB Aggregate Framework - Grouping with Multiple Fields in _id

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

*Before marking this question as a duplicate - please read through. I don't think a sufficiently conclusive and general answer has been given yet, as most questions have focused on specific examples.*

The MongoDB documentation says that you can specify an aggregate key for the _id value of a $group operation. There are a number of previously answered questions about using MongoDB's aggregate framework to group over multiple fields in this way, i.e:

```
{$group: {_id:{field_a:'$field_a', field_b:'$field_b'} } }
```

Q: In the most general sense, what does this action do?

- If grouping documents by field A condenses any documents sharing the same value of field A into a single document, does grouping by fields A and B condense documents with matching values of both A and B into a single document?
- Is the grouping operation sequential?
- If so, does that imply any level of precedence between 'field_a' and 'field_b' depending on their ordering?

Answer (score 1):

> If grouping documents by field A condenses any documents sharing the same value of field A into a single document, does grouping by fields A and B condense documents with matching values of both A and B into a single document?

Let `A = { a:A, b:B }`, then that automatically follows from the assumption. You didn't make any assumption about the *type* of A, which is correct: the type doesn't matter. If the type of A is *document*, the usual comparison rules apply (equal content is considered equal).

> Is the grouping operation sequential?

I'm not sure what that means. The aggregation pipeline runs accumulator functions on all items in each stage, so it certainly iterates the entire set, but I'd refrain from making assumptions about the exact order that happens in, i.e. from performing any non-associative operations.

> If so, does that imply any level of precedence between 'field_a' and 'field_b' depending on their ordering?

No, documents are compared field-by-field and [there are no strict guarantees on the ordering of fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-field-order) ("attempts to...") in MongoDB. However, one can, in principle, create documents that contain multiple fields of the same name where the ordering *might* matter. But it's hard to do so, since most client interfaces don't allow different fields of equal name.